# Inequation confusion

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

How does the inequation in part (1) turn from $|-z+b|^2<|-\bar{b}z+1|^2$ to $|z|^2+|b|^2<|b|^2|z|^2+1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the implication, expand both sides of the inequality using the relation $|z|^2 = z \bar{z}$.  Thus

$$|-z + b|^2 = (-z + b)(-\bar{z} + \bar{b}) = |z|^2 + |b|^2 - z\bar{b} - \bar{z}b$$

$$<$$

$$|-\bar{b}z + 1|^2 = (-\bar{b}z + 1)(-b\bar{z} + 1) = |b|^2|z|^2 + 1 - z\bar{b} - \bar{zb}$$

They contain a common term which you can cancel, and then it simplifies to the desired inequality.

The result $|z| < 1$ now follows from arithmetic:

$$|z|^2 + |b|^2 < |b|^2|z|^2 + 1 \iff |z|^2(1 - |b|^2) < 1 - |b|^2 \iff |z|^2 < 1 \iff |z| < 1$$
where in the second relation we relied on $|b|^2 < 1$ to divide without changing the direction of the inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for $|z|^2=\color{red}{z \bar z = 1}\,$:

$$
|f(z)|^2=\frac{(-z+b)(-\bar z + \bar b)}{(-\bar{b}z+1)(- b \bar z + 1)} = \frac{\color{red}{z \bar z} + b \bar b -b \bar z - \bar b z}{b \bar b \color{red}{z \bar z} + 1 -\bar b z - b \bar z}
$$